# Spring - unknown column in 'field list' ONLY when saving / POST (but read / GET works...)

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a problem with Spring I can't get over. I added many fields to classes and MySQL database, but this time I don't know what's happening.

The problematic field is `score`. I can retrieve the resource by GET and the field is returned by API, but any modification like POST new one throws `MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'score' in 'field list'`.

Here is my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resources")
@Audited
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id"})
public class Resource extends ResourceSupport implements Localizable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long resourceId;

    // ... other fields ...

    private Double score; // <== that's the one!

    public Double getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    // ... other getters and setters ...
}
```

In my database I have a `score` field defined this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `resources`  ( (...) 'score' double NOT NULL (...) )
```

I really don't get how it is possible that the field name matches but I still get the exception. **I went through all the similar threads on Stack** (about 10), but none addresses this specific issue...

Comment: Just in case, are you sure you're connecting to the same database you checked?

Comment: This error can also result from an inappropriate mapping across entities that involved the score column.  Do you have any joins across entities that involves the score column?

Comment: it's correct database, and there are no relationships involving this column. I ran on test database using ddl-auto=create, and now it works, so it's a database structure issue. I'm going to check and post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've found an issue. I use Hibernate Envers, a mechanism in Spring (since 2009) that allows you to store records history from selected tables. 
It automatically created `resources_aud` table for my `resources` table. Later I added the column to the `resource` table, but not to the `resource_aud` table.

BTW, I recommend Hibernate Envers. It's amazingly simple in use. You just add `@Audited` tag and that's all.